# Is the movement and ghost AI in the Super Nintendo Ms. Pac Man faithful to the arcade version?

Tags: version-differences, pac-man

I have the SNES version of Ms. Pac Man. It has many obvious graphical differences and optional changes compared to the arcade version, but I'm not sure if the gameplay is the same when you select the most arcade-like options. For example, the original and very well documented Pac Man (not necessarily Ms. Pac Man) has "rounded corner" turns for the main character, but this doesn't seem to happen in the SNES version of Ms. Pac Man.

Comment: Off-topic, but I really enjoyed this article about Pac Man's mechanics: http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Comment: Yes, every aspect of the /original/ Pac-Man is documented in excruciating detail.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Ms. Pac-Man Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms._Pac-Man) page:

> The ghosts' behavior patterns are
>   different and include semi-random
>   movement, precluding the use of
>   patterns to beat each level.

The page also mentions a few other changes to game mechanics, such as the fruit that now moves and multiple mazes, although there is nothing to suggest that the player control was changed.

From the same page:

> The Mega Drive/Genesis, Master System,
>   and NES versions, by Tengen, and the
>   Super NES version, by Williams
>   Electronics, took a few liberties.

**Based on this information you should not expect Ms. Pac-Man to behave the same as the classic arcade Pac-Man.**

Comment: Of course Ms. Pac Man is different than Pac Man. I wasn't sure whether the liberties affected the gameplay, but it's still quite fun :-)

Comment: I think they meant the arcade version of Ms. Pac Man, not the original Pac Man.